# Check if bit is changed

Tags: c, bit

I want transmit the state of a bit. When it is set, it should be transmetted for 10 secondes even if its status changes.

here is my solution:

```
 unsigned long Time;
 unsigned char State;
 unsigned char Flag;/*It is set by an other function*/
 unsigned char Bit;     
 #define BITDETECTION 1
 #define COUNT        2

void My_Function ()
{
  Bit = (Flag == 0)?0:1;
 switch(State)
  {
    case BITDETECTION:
    if(Bit == 0) Transmitte(Bit);
    else {State = COUNT; time = GetTime();/*Get the current time*/}
    break;
    case COUNT:
    if( GetTime() - time) <= 10 ) Transmitte(Bit);
    else State = BITDETECTION;
    break;
    default:break;
  }
}
```

Is it correct?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the description is a bit vague...

Comment: When `State == COUNT`, you should always `Transmitte(1)`

Comment: @user3386109: yes even if its status changes to 0.

Comment: I *think* it will work if you fix the errors, but if I was the code manager I would make you rewrite it.  I would simply use millie's in a while loop when "bit" was high.  By the way getTime() returns a struct which only resolves to a second, but if timing is not that critical then I suppose it would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposal:

```
void My_Function ()
{
  Bit = (Flag == 0)?0:1;
  switch(State)
  {
  case COUNT:
    if( GetTime() - time) <= 10 )
    {
      Transmitte(Bit);
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      State = BITDETECTION;
      /* fall through to next case */
    }
  case BITDETECTION:
    if(Bit != 0)
    {
       State = COUNT;
       time = GetTime();/*Get the current time*/
    }
    Transmitte(Bit);
    break;
  default: abort();
  }
}
```